# Calculating sample size

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I am going to conduct a research and would like to estimate the sample size that I will need.
Here is the information that I have, please let me know if you need some more information.
Thanks in advance.

We know from previous research that the probability of phenomena in one group (control group) is 1.1% and in another independent group (research group) is 19.4%.
I would like to check, what are the differences between those 2 groups in several demographics characteristic by using t-test and non parametric test. Alpha of 0.05%

What is the sample size that I should take?

Comment: -1, We aren't here to calculate your sample size for you. If you want to ask about how sample size calculations are done, you should clarify. You might also switch to the `[power-analysis]` tag, as the `[sample-size]` tag's excerpt suggests. Finally, if you have two %s, you should not be using a t-test.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me clarify.
I would like to calculate the sample size and I will be glad to get an answer and explanation how to do the calculation.
I would like to compare 2 groups at parameters like age (by years), proportion of female etc.
I know that the probability of phenomena in one group (control group) is 1.1% and in another independent group (research group) is 19.4%.
So I want to know what are the minimal groups size that I need in order to find significant differences.
Thanks